# Restoring a Windows 8 image on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-8, system-restore

I have an SSD notebook that I had upgraded to Windows 8 and I have saved a system image. The SSD had a problem and was repaired under warranty but in the process they restored a Windows 7 OS.

Is there any way to restore the Windows 8 image given that I now have a Windows 7 system to work with?

Comment: Doesn't seem very researched. A single google search for "System image windows 8" comes up with plenty of results.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Windows 8 DVD and select **System Image Recovery** in the Repair Options [image].

Here select the Image

[image]

click next and start to Restore Windows.

Comment: Its an Asus Ultrabook. No DVD drive and originally sold with Win7. I upgraded to Win8 on-line so I don't have a Win8 DVD anyway.

I saved the image on an external drive connected via USb and it is clearly there when i look with Win7. I also copied it to the root of the SSD and made it available via the network on a mapped drive from a network store, so it is there in three places. If I try to access it via the Win7 Restore utility it does not find it, won't show it. Hence my original question.

Comment: I am unable to vote down your answer as i don't have the required reputation score but so that you know, your answer was illconsidered and unhelpful.

Comment: you no longer get help if you troll around. You can create an bootable USB drive and boot from it: http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-8-iso-from-microsoft-using-product-key/

Comment: I am of the opinion that the correct answer to my original question is no. I was looking to save time and effort but to no avail. I have downloaded a fresh copy of Win8 and am working with that. I do not understand your comment that I "no longer get help" when I didn't get any in the 1st place. Regards

Comment: where the hell should I know that you don't have a DVD? You haven't posted your hardware info. Because of your 2nsd troll reply I'll no longer help you.